# Should I replace the entire garage door or just the 2 panels?

Tags: garage-door

I idiotically backed my car into the garage door. The door is still functional and closes and opens normally via the opener. I also tried manual opening and closing and does not feel any different.

The main damage seems to be right between where the middle panel and the bottom panel joins in the center.

[image]

The middle and the panel above it (below the top window panel) also has a small dent from the outside, but very small, about 3 inch wide.

I read online that if 2 or more panels need to be replaced, it is best to just get a whole new door.

So, should I opt for panel replacement or door replacement?

Thanks

Comment: If the door is still operational, I would bend the dents back out. Of it won't seal, then the question would be, can you get replacement panels? I don't see why you would need to replace the whole door, other than cost effectiveness.

Comment: The answer will probably become evident when you price replacement panels and replacement doors. There's also the consideration of whether a replacement door might offer a useful upgrade (such as being an insulated. or better-insulated door, if the old door is not) or whether that is not a factor that would matter for your garage.